# Inheritance with JUnit

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I have two classes (B & C) that extend from A.

I am trying to write a unit test in a way that I can just pass in concrete implementations of B and C and let them run.  For example:

```
abstract class A {
  abstract doSomething();

  public static void send(A a){
      // sends a off
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public void doSomething(){
    this.send(this)
  }

class C extends A {
  public void doSomething(){
    this.send(this);
    this.write(this)
  }
  public void write(A a){
     //writes A to file
  }
}
```

Now, I am looking for a way to unit test this abstractly and only have to pass in implementations and let the unit test run.  For example:

```
//setup junit testsuite info
class TestClassA {

  private A theClass;

  public void testDoSomething(){
     this.theClass.doSomething();
  }
}

 // would like to be able to do
class Runner {
   B b = new B();
   C c = new C();

   // run TestClassA with b (I know this doesnt work, but this is what I'd like to do)
   TestClassA.theClass = b;
   TestClassA.run();


   // run TestClassA with c (I know this doesnt work, but this is what I'd like to do)
   TestClassA.theClass = c;
   TestClassA.run();
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: A, B, & C are all concrete.  It also depends on what each instance is doing; if they're doing different things it makes sense to test them differently.  If they're doing the *same* thing as their parent class, it makes sense to just test the parent class and leave the other two alone.

Comment: whoops.  A is abstract.  Fixed above

Comment: They're doing different things, but they're doing them in the same method just different workflows for each implementation.  In the end the method signatures are all the same.

Comment: First of all, it looks like your system under test is your doSomething() method.  To test this, you are going to need output of some sort that can be validated.  In general, it doesn't really make sense to unit test methods that return void, unless you just want to verify it doesn't throw an exception

Comment: It saves something to a DB or to disk.  I am verifying that the saving is done.  It doesn't return anything at the moment.  Possibly a boolean in the future.

Comment: So presumably, class A and class C also need to have something in there that know about specifics about file or DB you are persisting to.  This is going to turn a unit test into a messier, longer running integration test if you really need to include the persistence operation in your test.  If, on the other hand, you wanted to just test some business logic here, you could use mock objects to supply an alternate implementation of the backend.  As it is now, there is nothing to verify and nothing to mock.

Comment: @Gary, Please see my posted answer to this question.  I wasn't looking for logic, I was looking for an framework to run in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ATest {
    private A theClass;

    public ATest(A theClass) {
        this.theClass= theClass;
    }

    @Test
    public final void doSomething() {
        // make assertions on theClass.doSomething(theClass)
    }


    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> instancesToTest() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                    new Object[]{new B()},
                    new Object[]{new C()}
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I renamed your TestClassA class to MyController, since it sounds like the MyController is a part of the system under test.  With that, you can test it with your B and C classes like this:

```
public class HelloContTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomethingWithB() throws Exception {
        MyController controller = new MyController();
        controller.setTheClass(new B());
        controller.doSomething();
    }
    @Test
    public void testSomethingWithC() throws Exception {
        MyController controller = new MyController();
        controller.setTheClass(new C());
        controller.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, this can only verify that the method can be called without throwing any exception.  Your testrunner will mark it with an error if your implementation method throws an exception.  I find this simpler than adding logic to verify no exception being thrown.